# ruby on rails named scopes (searching)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a named scope (name) combination of first and last name and I'm wanting to use this in a search box.

I have the code below:

```
named_scope :full_name, lambda { |fn| {:joins => :actor, :conditions => ['first_name LIKE ? OR second_name LIKE ?', "%#{fn}%", "%#{fn}%"]} }

def self.search(search)
  if search
    self.find(:all, :conditions => [ 'full_name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
  else
    find(:all)
  end
end
```

but this doesn't work as it gives the following error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: full_name: SELECT * FROM "actors" WHERE (full_name LIKE '%eli dooley%')
```

Thanks in advance

Houlahan

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
def self.search(search)
  if search
    self.full_name(search)
  else
    find(:all)
  end
end
```

The named scope does not add a column to the database, but an easily accessible way to get records without typing conditions every time.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because the `:conditions` hash in the statement:

```
self.find(:all, :conditions => ['full_name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
```

—is looking for an actual column named `full_name` in the database table. Named scopes (simply called scopes in Rails 3) get implemented as class methods on the model, so instead you need to do this:

```
self.full_name(search)
```

- Ryan Bates has a nice [Railscast on named scopes](http://railscasts.com/episodes/108-named-scope) that you might find useful

Comment: i tried using the 

self.full_name(search) 

but now i get an error when trying to display all the actors: 

Association named 'actor' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it? the actor is used in the loop when displaying all the actors in the index page.

Comment: That's really a separate question. You need to post the association code within the model class that contains this named scope.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Searchlogic?

I highly recommend it.

http://github.com/binarylogic/searchlogic